# Accesing JSON Data in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to parse JSON data from a website (http://dropdelivery.vacau.com/). 
I am using alamofire to try and access the data

```
    let url = "http://dropdelivery.vacau.com/"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let jsonDic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
            let responseData = jsonDic["responseData"] as! NSDictionary
            print(responseData)
```

when I run this it returns nothing what am I doing wrong? Is there better way to approach the problem.

Comment: Your query produces no `json` but `html` page as stated in the answer below from Andy. You need another service `url` that have only json in response or you need take `json` from it `html` page that is between the tags `<body> ... </ body>` befor `let jsonDic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary` and in this case it will be no `responseJSON` type of request. For further work with the json have a great library: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you don't have valid JSON at that URL; it's wrapped by HTML so Alamofire cannot parse it.

If you take a look at the source of the URL you mentioned, you see this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Current Item</title>
</head>

<body> 

{"item":{"title":"Sorry were closed","price":null,"image":null}}      
</body>
</html>

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

To get it working, you need to only see this:

```
{"item":{"title":"Sorry were closed","price":null,"image":null}}
```